# Using string vs. integer identifiers in RESTful URLs

Tags: sql, database, github, restful-url, hateoas

How does one decide to use string vs. integer identifiers in RESTful URLs. For example, I see that the Github API uses strings in some cases, e.g.

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/nareshbhatia/git-explorer
=> get a repository whose id is "git-explorer"
```

whereas integers in others

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/1347
=> get an issue whose id is 1347
```

I understand that it is more natural to identify a repository by its name and an issue by its number, but from an implementation perspective a string identifier poses several issues. Should the primary key for the repository table be the name? But a string is generally a bad choice for a primary key. Ok so how about an integer surrogate key and make the name a unique column. But that means whenever I have a reference to a repository (an integer) and I need to construct a URL for it, I am forced to make a join to the repository table - just to get its name.

To clarify, suppose I am creating the JSON for an issue and I need to include a link to the repository, I need a join to the repository table to create a link like `/repos/nareshbhatia/git-explorer` instead of a simple link with just an integer reference like `/repos/nareshbhatia/10`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I agree with the statement that strings are a bad choice for a PK. Certainly if you are using a natural key, odds are good you're going to be using strings. Many people prefer integers because they are more compact and they improve performance in indices, but performance shouldn't be your only consideration, and there are advantages to natural keys. Enough about the database.

When you start talking about URIs, there really is no appreciable performance advantage to shorter URLs, so integers don't have performance as an edge over strings. String also have an SEO advantage over integers in an URI. These considerations might lead you to design your database with integer primary keys, but use strings as URIs in your restful endpoints.

Comment: I was myself inclined to go for strings as PK, but the opinions on the net seem to be 50-50. Also I was thinking that if such large keys appears as foreign keys in associated tables, that does not feel right. That's why the thought of a surrogate key as the PK. BTW, do people realy consider SEO advantage for RESTful API's? I thought that's only for browasble pages. (of course, I agree that a meaningful/readable URI even in the case of REStful APIs is much preferable.)